# what happens during ping to a web site ? what are the stages?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ping

I'm pretty new to networking, so it might sound stupid, but :

If I do:

```
ping www.google.com
```

what are the steps that are needed  so that the ping will get to this website?

I know there is a conversion from name to ip by DNS (is this the very first step)?

there should also be an ARP request ? (after getting ip address from DNS) ?

what other stages are there?

I tried using wireshark but it got me even more confused...

thanks

Comment: you could describe it using different levels of abstraction. At the socket level, you could look at the code to see what happens. Here's an [implementation in Python](https://gist.github.com/zed/255009#file-ping-py-L131). If you want much more details, you could start with how computer receives your input e.g., see [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer networking

Answer (score 5):

1. The ping application crafts a ICMP ping packet to the destination and submits it to the network stack
2. The IP layer uses the routing table to determine the interface the packet should be sent out on and whether it should be addressed to the destination host or an intermediate network gateway
3. ARP uses the destination IP to determine the MAC that correlates to the nexthop IP address, looking it up via a network broadcast request if it is not in the ARP resolution table
4. The network layer crafts the frame using the ethernet MAC addressing passed in by ARP
5. The frame is sent on the wire
6. The network routes the packet to the destination host.
7. The destination IP stack replies to the ping
8. The ping response routes back.
9. The ping response frame arrives at your computer and travels through the network stack
10. The network stack hands the ping response packet to the ping application, which determines and displays elapsed time.

Comment: thanks for you reply. What about the fact that it's a ping to server name and not to ip address ?

Comment: Packets don't contain hostnames, so the ping application needs to look up the destination IP vis DNS to craft the packet. Usually delegated to operating system, may or may not recurse.